# MySQL Call script from command line, but don't exit the session

Tags: mysql

I have 15+ Mysql database on different machines and call each of them manually through the command line. I have replaced those commands with an alias and created a windows batch file using DOSKEY

example of running the alias:

```
c:\Projects>DOSKEY mysql_db1=mysql -u staffing -p staffing -e "select database(), user();"

c:\Projects>mysql_db1
Enter password: ********
+------------+--------------------+
| database() | user()             |
+------------+--------------------+
| staffing   | staffing@localhost |
+------------+--------------------+

c:\Projects>
```

This works fine, but is there a way to not exit the MySQL prompt?
Basically, for each database that I log in, I should see that its the correct database and run other commands without exit.

Is it possible with MySQL?

Comment: Download MySQL Workbench and you'll be able to have different connections to other computer across the network from single place with constant database connection.

Comment: Thanks @Anton , I have MySQL Workbench, but this is not what I want. I want to run from command promot.

Comment: Alas, completing mysql commands (even in batch mode) also terminates entire batch process. Possible walkaround - connect manually and then perform necessary tasks from external file (typing "source <filename>" in mysql console) and keep connection.

Comment: Thanks @Anton, I switched to using --prompt. Its not exactly what I want, but close.

mysql --prompt="\u@\h [DB:\d]> " -u user1 -p db1